# "For which a, b, t ∈ N does Ka,b contain a copy of Ct?"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

the question involves finding values for $a,b,t$ such that we have a cycle of length $t$ in the complete bipartite graph $Ka,b$.  Heres my attempt:

Clearly $t$ must be even and larger than 3 in order to be a cycle in a bipartite graph.  $a$ and $b$ don't have to be equal, so long as the smaller of the two is greater than or equal to $t/2$ then the graph will contain a cycle.  Hence my values are:

$t > 2n$ where $n$ is a natural number greater than 1,

$\min(a,b)\ge t/2$.

Is that sufficient?

Cheers !

Comment: Yes, that works.